# NoMethodError: undefined method `find' for "Truck":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok i want to switch the name of the model by the value of a field

this is what i have:

```
type = notification.notification_type.capitalize
post = type.find(post_id)
```

Type will be Truck, Load, or Hotload

error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `find' for "Truck":String
```

I guess it is trying to do this:

```
post = "Truck".find(post_id)
```

instead of this

```
post = Truck.find(post_id)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats correct. You are trying to use `find` method on String.

You can use `type.constantize.find(post_id)`

Comment: thanks... that is what i am looking for. I will accept when it will allow me to... thanks a million. I am new to ruby and still figuring it all out